# officedown readonly output

Tags: r, r-markdown, officedown

I am creating an `officedown` `docx` file and the file created is in read only mode. Is there a way to have it be in compatibility mode?

Here is the Rmd file.

````
---
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
author: "Your Name"
title: "officedown template"
output: 
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    mapstyles:
      Normal: ['First Paragraph']
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.cap = TRUE, fig.path = 'figures/test/')
library(officedown)
library(officer)
library(ggplot2)

fp <- fp_par(
  text.align = "center", 
  padding.bottom = 20, padding.top = 120, 
  border.bottom = fp_border())

ft <- fp_text(shading.color='#EFEFEF', bold = TRUE)
```

\newpage

This document presents most of the features of the package `r ftext("officedown", ft)`. 
`r fp`

## Table of content

<!---BLOCK_TOC--->

## List of figures

<!---BLOCK_TOC{seq_id: 'fig'}--->

## List of tables

<!---BLOCK_TOC{seq_id: 'tab'}--->


\newpage

## figures 

### A boxplot

```{r plot, include=FALSE, dpi=300, fig.dim = c(10,7)}
ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg), data = mtcars) + 
  geom_boxplot()

# ggsave(filename = 'plot.png',path = 'figures/test', plot = p, dpi = 300)
```

```{r,  fig.cap="A boxplot", fig.id = "boxplot",dpi=300}
knitr::include_graphics('figures/test/plot-1.png')
```
````

output file info screenshot

[image: output]

Session Info

```r
- Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
 os       Windows 10 x64              
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 ctype    English_United States.1252  
 tz       America/New_York            
 date     2021-06-08                  

- Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ! package     * version    date       lib source                             
 P askpass       1.1        2019-01-13 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P assertthat    0.2.1      2019-03-21 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P backports     1.1.10     2020-09-15 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P cachem        1.0.5      2021-05-15 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P cli           2.5.0      2021-04-26 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P clipr         0.7.0      2019-07-23 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P colorspace    1.4-1      2019-03-18 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P crayon        1.4.1      2021-02-08 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P desc          1.2.0      2018-05-01 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P details       0.2.1      2020-01-12 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P digest        0.6.27     2020-10-24 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P dplyr         1.0.6      2021-05-05 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P ellipsis      0.3.2      2021-04-29 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P evaluate      0.14       2019-05-28 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P fansi         0.4.1      2020-01-08 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P farver        2.0.3      2020-01-16 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P fastmap       1.1.0      2021-01-25 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
   gdtools       0.2.3      2021-01-06 [1] standard (@0.2.3)                  
 P generics      0.1.0      2020-10-31 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P ggplot2     * 3.3.3      2020-12-30 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
   ggtext        0.1.1      2020-12-17 [1] standard (@0.1.1)                  
 P glue          1.4.2      2020-08-27 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
   gridtext      0.1.4      2020-12-10 [1] standard (@0.1.4)                  
 P gtable        0.3.0      2019-03-25 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P here          0.1        2017-05-28 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
   htmltools     0.5.1.1    2021-01-22 [1] standard (@0.5.1.1)                
 P httr          1.4.2      2020-07-20 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P keyring       1.2.0      2021-04-28 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P knitr         1.30       2020-09-22 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P labeling      0.3        2014-08-23 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P lifecycle     1.0.0      2021-02-15 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P magrittr      2.0.1      2020-11-17 [?] standard (@2.0.1)                  
 P memoise       2.0.0      2021-01-26 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P munsell       0.5.0      2018-06-12 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
   officedown  * 0.2.2      2021-04-05 [1] standard (@0.2.2)                  
 P officer     * 0.3.19.004 2021-06-07 [?] Github (davidgohel/officer@5943a7d)
 P openssl       1.4.3      2020-09-18 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
   pak           0.1.2.9001 2021-06-07 [1] local                              
 P pillar        1.6.1      2021-05-16 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P pkgconfig     2.0.3      2019-09-22 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P png           0.1-7      2013-12-03 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P purrr         0.3.4      2020-04-17 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P R6            2.5.0      2020-10-28 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P Rcpp          1.0.5      2020-07-06 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
   renv          0.13.2     2021-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P rlang         0.4.11     2021-04-30 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P rmarkdown     2.5        2020-10-21 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P rprojroot     1.3-2      2018-01-03 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P rstudioapi    0.13       2020-11-12 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
   rvg           0.2.5      2020-06-30 [1] standard (@0.2.5)                  
 P scales        1.1.1      2020-05-11 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P sessioninfo   1.1.1      2018-11-05 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
   systemfonts   1.0.2      2021-05-11 [1] standard (@1.0.2)                  
 P tibble        3.1.2      2021-05-16 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P tidyr         1.1.3      2021-03-03 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P tidyselect    1.1.0      2020-05-11 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P utf8          1.2.1      2021-03-12 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P uuid          0.1-4      2020-02-26 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P vctrs         0.3.8      2021-04-29 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P withr         2.3.0      2020-09-22 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P xfun          0.18       2020-09-29 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P xml2          1.3.2      2020-04-23 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P yaml          2.2.1      2020-02-01 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     
 P zip           2.1.0      2020-08-10 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                     

[1] C:/Users/jonathan.sidi/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpqMBfHk/renv-system-library

 P -- Loaded and on-disk path mismatch.
```

Comment: Hi. Is it when you click on 'knit' when using RStudio? I never understood why Word files are opened as "read-only". I use rmarkdown::render + browseURL but it's not really satisfying if you only want to 'knit' and then edit.

Comment: Yes. when I click "knit" in RS. I dont have a problem to use the console if that means it will be in compatible mode.

Comment: Then something like this should be ok and quite close to what the knitr button is doing: `rmarkdown::render("path/to/your.Rmd", envir = new.env());
browseURL("path/to/your.docx")`

Answer (score 0):

I fell on this post after trying to figure out how to change the default zoom once a docx is rendered using officer. I was able to use the code @David Gohel provided along with the [shrtcts](https://pkg.garrickadenbuie.com/shrtcts/articles/shrtcts.html#where-to-store-your-shortcuts) package. Below is the code I used. I can remap the shortcut to whatever I want.

```
#' Say Something Nice
#'
#' A demo of cool things.
#'
#' @interactive
#' @shortcut Ctrl+Alt+P
praise::praise

#' knit to word custom
#'
#' Trying to fix zoom error in Word when rendering docx
#'
#' @shortcut Ctrl+Shift+K
function(){
  rmarkdown::render("manuscript.Rmd", envir = new.env()); 
  browseURL("manuscript.docx")
}
```